# Git numeric tags

Tags: git, git-tag

When trying to use numeric tags in git, such as 1000, I run into an issue where Git thinks that I am trying to specify hash instead of a tag.

***Is there a way to tell Git client to not try to think of specified version as SHA1 unless length is say 6 characters?***

I.e. I want Git to think of 1000, 22000 as tags, and 1F3DEE as SHA1

Comment: just add some prefix. People usually create tags like that: `v1.0.0` `version/1.0.0` (I prefer this one, it is more flexible). Later in script it is very easy to strip this prefix.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing now, but I'd like to see if I can get away w/o a prefix.

Comment: can you explain what will you gain by doing this?

Comment: *I want Git to think of 1000, 22000 as tags, and 1F3DEE as SHA1.* And what if your repo contains an object that has a SHA of  beginning with `1000` or `22000`? What then?

Comment: Exactly. That's my question: Is there a way to tell Git client to not think of specified numeric string as SHA1 unless length is, say, 6 characters?

Comment: @MarekR - I am exploring my options, trying to see if this can be done, and if there's some kind of switch in Git that would allow to tweak length of numeric string Git would consider SHA1.